# Replacing regex group results - is it possible?

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate HTML link, plus at the same time extract "http/https", host and address part. Is it possible to change group 1 value, let's say if it is "https" - the output would be "true" value:

```
String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1M9TJpLTcw8   ";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?i)(https?)://(.{3,}?)/(.*?) *$");//(?i) - for case insensitive
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("g1: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("g2: " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("g3: " + m.group(3));
}
```

The output is:

```
g1: https//But I want to replace it - when "http" - it would be "false", "https" - "true"
g2: www.youtube.com
g3: watch?v=1M9TJpLTcw8
```

Comment: `System.out.println("g1: " + "https".equals(m.group(1)) ? "true" : "false");`?

Comment: Also use `https?` instead of seperately checking for both :P

Comment: Why not just call `replaceAll("^https:","http:")` and then find the groups?

Comment: @TheLostMind I want to know if it is secure protocol or not also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
g1 = "http".equals(m.group(1)) ? "false" : "true"
```

Comment: Seems to be the only way... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("g1: " + (m.group(1) != null && m.group(1).equals("https")) ? true : false);
```

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis No i do not think so.

Comment: @Jens it's easier if you call equals on the string literal, then you don't have to do the null check.